# $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$,estimator for $N$(continuation)

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X_i$, $i\geq 1$, be independent and identically distributed random variables having the uniform distribution over $(0,1)$. Let $X$ be defined as $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$, where $N$ is an unknown integer.
>
> (a) Find an unbiased estimator $T(X)$ of $N$.
>
> (b) Decide with adequate reasons, if $\dfrac{T(X)}{N}$ converges to $1$ almost surely, as $N$ goes to infinity.

Now, in my previous question I wanted to know something different ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783131/x-sum-i-1nx-i-estimator-for-n)) but not the solution. So, I tried to find the solution after @Ben's hint.

Now, we know that $E(2X)=N$. But since, $2X$ is not always natural number, I need to find the value, $E([2X]+1)$. Here, $[\cdot]$ is box function.

To do that, we need to find the distribution of $[2X]$.

Now, $P([2X]=k)=P(k\leq 2X<k+1)$, $k=0,1,\dots,2N-1$

Although, I could not find a way to compute $P(k\leq 2X<k+1)$. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be assuming a requirement that the estimator only yield integer values, but you didn't formulate such a requirement in the problem statement.

Comment: It's allowed to formulate your own estimator, and then ask what properties it has.  In the present case you ask how to compute $\mathbf{Pr}(k\le 2X \lt k+1)$.  Of course I'm sure you realize this is also $\mathbf{Pr}((k/2)\le X \lt (k+1)/2)$, so it is directly found from the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @hardmath it is hard to find distribution of $X$ for any $N$.

Comment: However hard it is, it is essentially the point of your Question to evaluate the cumulative distribution function for $X$ at the values $x=k/2$.  I'm posting this Comment because I'd like some clarity in what your Question asks.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too complicated. If you want the estimator to always yield integer values, just round it to the nearest integer. The invariance under $X_i\to1-X_i$ ensures that the rounding errors are unbiased.

Comment: i didn't understand the application of invariance here.  Can you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: @Stat_prob_001: If some instantiation of the random variables yields the rounding error $\epsilon$, the equally likely instantiation where each $X_i$ is replaced by $1-X_i$ yields the opposite rounding error $-\epsilon$. Hence the expectation of the rounding errors vanishes.